# execute class from included layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, include

Within my layout I have set a `Include Other Layout`. this layout schould in his turn show a `listview` with items loaded from the web (my webserver)

the only problem is: the items don't load in because the class that holds the code to load the items isnt called on because im using a `Include Other Layout` meaning only the layout is called and not the functional code from any .java files (classes)

leaving me with a blank page...

is there a way to make a call upon the class containing the code for the layout i have `included`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<include/>` tag is only for including only the view into another layout. It can be very useful if you use a common view everywhere. A `ProgressBar` can be an example. You can include `ProgressBar` everywhere you want. But it is just a UI.

If you also want the functionality you should use `Fragments`. Actually `Fragments` are exactly for what you describe.

Here is the tutorial from Android Developers official website
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html